# 2001 Chevy Impala Radio problem

Tags: chevrolet, audio, impala

I am trying to put a new stereo in and my alarm goes off when I hook it up. Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!